# Chrome Postman add a certificate to the request sent to a service

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, certificate, postman

Is it possible to pass a certificate in the request being sent by Postman? Basically I need the Postman to send a request to a service so that when the service receives the HttpRequestMessage(request) and does a request.GetClientCertificate(), it will get the certificate being sent by the postman request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that if I enter a https url, Postman gives a pop-up with certificates installed on the computer, which allows to select a certificate and attach to the request. The service which received this request is able to do a request.GetClientCertificate() and get the certificate in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the certificate as a header in your request. To get the value, export the certificate from the certificate store as a base64 encoded file. Open the certificate file in notepad and viola ! You will be able to use the following code :

```
 var token = headers.GetValues("X-ARR-ClientCert").First();
 var cert = pCert.GetClientCertificateFromHeader(token);
```